# phpinfo() not showing xdebug when tried remotely while shows while tried locally

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a website sample.com on web server (whose ip is 192.168.1.66)

I have created a file called test.php in the website folder public_html with the following code.

```
<?php

phpinfo();
?>
```

I am on a pc with ip 192.168.4.10. In my /etc/hosts i have the following

```
192.168.1.66 sample.com
192.168.1.66 www.sample.com
```

In firefox I open the url `sample.com/test.php` it shows lot of output but no xdebug related things

while i go to the folder where test.php is located and run

```
php test.php
```

In the output it shows

xdebug

```
xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.3.3
IDE Key => 1

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => 1 => 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 100 => 100
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /tmp/xdebug.log => /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => On => On
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => -1 => -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data => -1 => -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => -1 => -1
```

I dont know what is happening. How to make xdebug parameters show up in phpinfo() funtion when used remotely. Because if this works, i can try for remote debugging.

Comment: Did you restart apache/nginx?

Comment: yes. I restarted apache many times

Comment: Check to make sure you have the right version for your OS..

Comment: I have everything right. because its working on local.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the xdebug DLL.

Comment: Ok. i think there is no issue with xebug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83899/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-half-crazed).